# How do I give user sudo access to modify files in certain directories /etc/

Tags: linux, sudoers

I have a user who needs to modify files in /etc/haproxy and /etc/tomcat.  I tried to create a `sudoers` file with:

```
%usergroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/haproxy /etc/tomcat
```

But it didn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sudoers won't give you the type of control you need. Instead, consider using groups. Assuming that those programs run as root:

1. Define a new group
2. Modify the group for those directories to be the new group.
3. Give the group read/write permission to those directories.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the group via setfacl and it worked.